# Pandas GroupBy Making columns able to be referenced

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Is there any way to make all columns created by Panadas.groupby() able to referenced? I am currently only able to call the aggregated column.

```
bikes = final_merged_df.loc[final_merged_df['Category'] == 'Bikes', ['year', 'Subcategory', 'Category', 'OrderQty']].groupby([pandas.Grouper(key='Subcategory'), pandas.Grouper(key='year')]).sum()
```

returns a table like this:

[image: Screenshot #1]

but I am unable to call the 'subcategory' field, or create a multi-bar chart using the 'subcategory' as colors.

If I can't call it, is there any way to fill in this data frame (i.e. Mountain Bikes fills down for 2011-2014, so does Road Bikes, etc.) to a new dataframe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be **_GREAT_** to get a sample of your data to work with :)

Comment: kindly share sample dataframe (text, or even better as a dictionary), and include your expected output dataframe

Comment: You can reset_index(), then everything becomes a referenceable as you'd like OR you can review how to slice multiindex here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html  you most likely have a level=0 and a level=1, so you can filter by specifying the level, among other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jonathan Leon in the comments. `unstack()` plus `set_index()` was exactly what I needed. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!